# Angular $resource and use of Interceptor to check response/error/callback

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Last few days I am working to invoke REST services and track the response, error, callback etc. I have gone through most of the posting however due to my limited understanding on Angular seems like I am not able to understand it. Following is my problem and understanding I got so far.

I am using Project.$update() service which returns only "project_id". This server doesn't return complete data again. Following is line of few line of code to share here.

```
//create Project factory
app.factory('Project', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/projects/:projectid',
            {projectid:'@id'},
            {update: {method:'PUT', isArray:false}}    
    );

});
```

Following is code in directive I am using to update/create project.

```
//save project
            scope.saveProject = function (project) {
                //update modified by field
                project.modifiedby = scope.user._id;
                //change to view mode
                scope.projectView = 1;
                //call server to save the data                
                if (project._id == undefined || project._id == "") {

                    //Call server to create new and update projectID
                    project._id = project.$save()._id;
                }
                else {
                    //Call server to update the project data
                    project.$update({ projectid: project._id });
                }


            };
```

Following is service response for both save() and update().

```
{"_id":"52223481e4b0c4d1a050c25e"}
```

Problem here is; "project" object value is replaced by new response returned by server having only project_id and other fields are replaced.

I was going through detailed documentation on $resource however I am not able to grasp it. It will be great to get some guidance here to write code to detect error, response, callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion made by  jvandemo and BoxerBucks; I have used following approach for save/update by passing the callback method with copy of original data. However still I am looking for central approach to take care of error/success status. Please suggest.

```
//save project metadta
            scope.saveProjectMetadta = function (project) {

                //update modified by field
                project.modifiedby = scope.user._id;
                //change to view mode
                scope.projectView = 1;
                //keep original data to pass into callback
                var originalProjectObject = angular.copy(project);
                //call server to save the data                
                if (project._id == undefined || project._id == "") {                    
                    //Call server to create new and update projectID
                    project.$save(originalProjectObject, function (projectResponse) {
                        originalProjectObject._id = projectResponse._id;
                        //update scope
                        scope.project = originalProjectObject;
                        //invoke method to update controller project object state
                        scope.updateProjectScope(scope.project);
                    });

                }
                else {
                        //Call server to update the project data
                        project.$update({ projectid: project._id }, function (projectResponse) {

                        originalProjectObject._id = projectResponse._id;
                        //update scope
                        scope.project = originalProjectObject;
                        //invoke method to update controller project object state
                        scope.updateProjectScope(scope.project);

                    },originalProjectObject);

                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the original object by the one returned from the server in your success callback like this:

```
        //save project
        scope.saveProject = function (project) {

            //update modified by field
            project.modifiedby = scope.user._id;

            //change to view mode
            scope.projectView = 1;

            //call server to save the data                
            if (project._id == undefined || project._id == "") {

                //Call server to create new and update projectID
                project.$save(function(updatedProject, headers){

                    // Replace project by project returned by server
                    project = updatedProject;
                });
            }
            else {
                //Call server to update the project data
                project.$update(function(updatedProject, headers){

                    // Replace project by project returned by server
                    project = updatedProject;
                });
            }

        };
```

That will replace the original object by the one returned by the server as soon as the server response is received.

If your callback is identical for the `$save` and `$update` methods, you can further simplify your code like this:

```
        //save project
        scope.saveProject = function (project) {

            //update modified by field
            project.modifiedby = scope.user._id;

            //change to view mode
            scope.projectView = 1;

            var action = (angular.isDefined(project._id)) ? '$update' : '$save';

            //call server to save the data                
            project[action](function(updatedProject, headers){

                // Replace project by project returned by server
                project = updatedProject;
            });

        };
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't think it will work...because as i mentioned earlier; server is not returning complete project object; instead of that server is only returning "project_id"

Comment: I just tried this approach however it didn't work.....it will be great if you can share other approach. I am really stuck here.

Comment: If you are following the REST standard then the server should respond with the object created or updated. This is because the server can normalize data e.g. adjust casing or formatting and thus the response reflects the normalized data. You cannot safely assume that the user input is valid unless it is returned by the server. So in essence if you have control over the server side, it is strongly recommended that you return the updated object as the body of the response (json) with an appropriate HTTP status code.

Comment: Server side API is managed by other team and I really doubt that they will agree to change the code to return the bulk data in response. Do we have any other solution?

Comment: Yes, you can clone the object before it is saved and assign the clone in the success callback once the save has succeeded. That should give you the desired result.

Comment: I'm currently finding that replacing the original object like this creates some kind of memory leak. When you replace project with the response body, you are actually changing the pointer in memory of where project points to. Some of your directives might be using the original project, where as others might be using the new one. This will have bad effects if you change object properties, but don't see any UI changes.